# Converting a SQLite file to .csv or .xml and vice-versa

Tags: xml, database, windows, sqlite, csv

I am working on a Windows machine. Is there any application or other way to convert a whole SQLite database (`.sqlite` file) to `.csv` or `.xml` and vice-versa? *i.e.* I should be able to convert the converted `.xml` or `.csv` back to a `.sqlite` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can export out of SQLite to multiple formats (eight different formats: "csv", "column", "html", "insert", "line", "list", "tabs", and "tcl"), here's how to export to list format

```
sqlite> .mode list
sqlite> .separator |
sqlite> .output test_file_1.txt
sqlite> select * from tbl1;
sqlite> .exit
$ cat test_file_1.txt
hello|10
goodbye|20
$
```

For importing back in

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import C:/work/somedata.csv tab1
```

There are 2 cases to consider: (1) Table "tab1" does not exist or (2) table "tab1" does exist.

for (1), the first row of the CSV file is interpreted to be column names and the actual data starts on the second row of the CSV file.

For (2), when the table exists, every row of the CSV file, including the 1st, is assumed to be actual content. If the CSV file contains an initial row of column labels, that row will be read as data and inserted into the table.

Make sure you try it on a test system first though ;)

Comment: sqlite> .mode csv
    sqlite> .import C:/work/somedata.csv tab1

There are 2 cases to consider: (1) Table "tab1" does not exist or (2) table "tab1" does exist. 

for (1), the first row of the CSV file is interpreted to be column names and the actual data starts on the second row of the CSV file. 

For (2), when the table exists, every row of the CSV file, including the 1st, is assumed to be actual content. If the CSV file contains an initial row of column labels, that row will be read as data and inserted into the table.    Make sure you do it on a test system first though ;)